# trying to understand something about php gd

Tags: php, gd

if i have something like this

```
<?php
$image = imagecreate(300,20);
$background = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
$foreground = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);


imagestring($image,5,5,1,'sarmenhb, $foreground);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

how does php know the first imagecolorallocate function will be my background witout even specifying it? what if i have multiple functions of that type listed. how will php associate which one ill be using for the background?

thnx

Answer (score 4):

According to the official PHP manual:

Note: The first call to imagecolorallocate() fills the background color in palette-based images - images created using imagecreate().

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php

Comment: ok thanks makes sense, i should've refered to the manual. but hopefully they'll change that in the future. it kind of doesnt make sense to newbees.

Comment: Grr Kane. I just finished typing my answer when yours appeared. :)

Comment: Haha hobodave it would seem you are quite the nemesis :P